# jQuery autoresize with live

Tags: jquery, live, autoresize

How can I use the jquery plugin "[autoresize](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/)" with JQuery's `live()` function best? The problem is, that the plugin creates an textarea behind the current one (with position absolute). When I use the jquery `live()` function I get stuck in an infinite loop, because the `textarea`, created by the script, gets another one and so on... Hope that you can follow me.

How can I use `live()` with that plugin?

Comment: Do you have any code samples you are using? Also, why do you need to use the `live()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `autoresize.jquery.js`, as you said, it creates a clone of the `textarea` to perform text size calculations. Here it is:

```
return textarea.clone().removeAttr('id').removeAttr('name').css({
```

As you see it strips `name` and `id` attributes. You could modify this line to add a `class` attribute which you can then filter out with your `$.live()` selector. E.g.

```
return textarea.clone().removeAttr('id').removeAttr('name').addClass('clone').css({
```

And

```
$('textarea:not(.clone)').live()
```